# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property but another property is found

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRM_LOG")
public class CrmLog implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private @Getter @Setter Long id;
    ..........
    @OneToOne
    private @Getter @Setter CrmUser crmUser;
}
```

and another entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRMUSER")
public class CrmUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer groupId;

public Integer getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
}
```

and I make hibernate criteria select

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("crmUser.id", selectedIds));
```

and it work fine. but this criteria is failed

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("crmUser.groupId", filterGroupIds));
```

I get an error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: crmUser.groupId of: crm.entity.CrmLog
```

Comment: Please post the full hibernate criteria query, it looks to me as if you are using CrmLog as a root and want to restrict the groupId which is CrmUser's property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("crmUser.id", selectedIds));
```

works because of `CrmLog` table has `CrmUser` `id` as a foreign key column. So Hibernate doesn't need to add joins in the SQL query.

To add restriction on other `CrmUser` properties you need to add an alias. Such alias tells to Hibernate to add join to the SQL request.

```
criteria.createAlias("crmUser", "user");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("user.groupId", filterGroupIds));
```

by default Hibernate adds an inner join. For a left join

```
criteria.createAlias("crmUser", "user", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("user.groupId", filterGroupIds));
```

`JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` can be used with Hibernate 5 (maybe Hibernate 4)

You can assign an alias to the root entity. Maybe such example is more  clear

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CrmLog.class, "log");
criteria.createAlias("log.crmUser", "user");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("user.groupId", filterGroupIds));
```